# Editar campos semelhantes no codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Imagine a seguinte situação:
Cadastrados em um banco de dados vários telefones de um único estabelecimento `(local_1, +55 xx xxxx-xxxX; local_1, +55 xx xxxx-xxxY; ...);`

O problema:
Possibilitar ao usuário editar estes vários telefones (isto inclui adicionar e remover) e salvar na base de dados isto.

Eu imaginei de listar os telefones e caso ocorra uma alteração, limpar da base de dados os telefones antigos e adicionar tudo de novo (a modificação)

Alguma sugestão para me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que você tenha uma tabela de estabelecimento e uma tabela de telefones, correto?

Recomendo fazer desse para que seus dados estejam (minimamente) [normalizados](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados#Formas_Normais).

Depois de ter essas duas tabelas, você poderá determinar através de um identificador único para cada telefone qual registro de telefone você está efetivamente editando ou removendo, através de uma [chave surrogate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) ou de alguma outra chave que considerar relevante ( ddd+número? ).

De posse desse identificador único, não é necessário remover todos os demais telefones, mas sim alterar apenas o telefone identificado por esse valor.

Comment: então, a minha tabela é constituída em [ID - DDD - TELEFONE - EMPRESA], para adicionar estes números de telefone, eu utilizo um jquery que me permite duplicar os campos, ou seja, uma empresa possui 0 ou mais telefones. O que eu quero fazer é permitir a exclusão de qualquer um dos telefones, também possibilitar a edição de qualquer um dos telefones e adicionar novos